# Proper syntax for this lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, mapping

I have a list A. And from that list, i want to create a new list B by using one field of list A for construction of objects in list B. However i am unable to get the syntax right. 
Currently i have

```
List<B> listB = listA.stream().map(id -> {
    ObjectB b = Mockito.mock(ObjectB.class);
    when(b.getId()).thenReturn(id.toString());
    when(b.getNumericId()).thenReturn(id); 
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However i am getting syntax error on map which i am unable to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have used `{}` for the lambda creation, you are supposed to use `return` also, thus:

```
  List<B> listB = listA.stream().map(id -> {
         ObjectB b = Mockito.mock(ObjectB.class);
         when(b.getId()).thenReturn(id.toString());
         when(b.getNumericId()).thenReturn(id); 
         return b;
  })
```

Comment: I have to admit: you were first ;)